# Why are we asked to"Join Stack *Overflow* in Standing Up for Net Neutrality"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, net-neutrality

How come all sites across the network are asking us to "Join **Stack Overflow** in Standing Up for Net Neutrality"? Shouldn't they ask us to "Join **Stack Exchange** in […]", or better yet, refer to the site that we're actually on?

(Tagging this as a "bug", though admittedly it's a minor one.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple years ago, we changed the name we use to identify our company [back to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). I won't reiterate all the implications of the name and how it's used here, as it's available in the blog, but this is a case where we'd rather identify as Stack Overflow so the larger audience recognizes the name.

Comment: I'm also going to add that within the linked blog post, this subject seems to affect Stack Overflow the most (Stack Exchange is not mentioned at all)

Comment: @AnthonyPham: Does this subject *actually* affect Stack Overflow the most? Or has the renaming of the company back to "Stack Overflow" led the linked blogger to forget about the rest of the network?

Comment: The linked blogger works for SE and of course Stack Overflow so he can't possibly forget the name of the company he works in. Within the subheadings and even the first sentence, the blog post is about the affect of the decision on Stack Overflow

Comment: @AnthonyPham: If that's so, then why is the banner being added to all other sites?